# jquery mobile app with json backend

Tags: jquery, html, json, web-applications

I have a jquery mobile app template without database(back end). I would like to add a json file with this project

**my json file**

```
    {
   "contact": [
       {
           "firstName": "Clark",
           "lastName": "Kent",
           "job": "Reporter",
           "location": "Delhi",
           "address": "No33 Villa",
           "phone": "9988xx99xx",
           "mobile": "9988xx99xx"
       },
       {
           "firstName": "Bruce",
           "lastName": "Wayne",
           "job": "Playboy",
           "location": "Mumbai",
           "address": "No33 Villa",
           "phone": "9988xx99xx",
           "mobile": "9988xx99xx"
       },
       {
           "firstName": "Peter",
           "lastName": "Parker",
           "job": "Photographer",
           "location": "Chennai",
           "address": "No33 Villa",
           "phone": "9988xx99xx",
           "mobile": "9988xx99xx"
       }
   ]
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
 <title>Contact Info</title> 
 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.1.css" />
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/launch_icon_57.png" />
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/launch_icon_72.png" />
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/launch_icon_114.png" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" />
 <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="c">

 <div data-role="content">
 
 <div id="branding">
  <h1>Contact Info</h1>
 </div>
 
 <div class="choice_list"> 
 <h1> What are you searching? </h1>
 
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
 <li><a href="choose_town.html" data-transition="slidedown">  <h3> xxx(json job title here)</h3></a></li>
 <li><a href="choose_town.html"  data-transition="slidedown"> <h3> xxx(json job title here)</h3></a></li>
 <li><a href="choose_town.html"  data-transition="slidedown">  <h3> xxx(json job title here)</h3></a></li>
 <li><a href="choose_town.html"  data-transition="slidedown">  <h3> xxx(json job title here)</h3></a></li>
 <li><a href="choose_town.html"  data-transition="slidedown">  <h3> xxx(json job title here)</h3></a></li>
 <li><a href="choose_town.html"  data-transition="slidedown">  <h3> xxx(json job title here)</h3></a></li> 
 </ul> 
 
 </div>
 </div>

</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So... what do you want to do? Add json file to?

Comment: #Ayushgp "yes, my json file not yet added with this project."